Why is attn_mask in PyTorch' MultiheadAttention specified for each head separately?
PyTorch MultiheadAttention allows to specify the attention mask, either as 2D or as 3D. The former will be broadcasted over all N batches the latter allows one to specify specific masks for each example in the batch. All seems to make sense. However, from the documentation, the 3D mask is defined as follows:

(N⋅num_heads,L,S), where N is the batch size, L is the target sequence
length, and S is the source sequence length.

Two questions araise:

Why would anyone want a different mask for different heads?
If we have to do it this way anyway, how are they ordered? i.e. is it (Example1, Head1), (Example1, Head2),... etc OR is it (Example1, Head1), (Example2, Head1),... ? This is also asked in the comments at this question.



Why would anyone want a different mask for different heads?

Because we want each head to capture different contextual relations between the elements in a sequence (ex: words in a sentence). For example, if the input sentence is "The animal didn't cross the street because it was too wide". Then head-1 might give more attention to the words "animal" and "it" and head-2 might give more attention to the words "street" and "it".

If we have to do it this way anyway, how are they ordered? i.e. is it (Example1, Head1), (Example1, Head2),... etc OR is it (Example1, Head1), (Example2, Head1),... ? This is also asked in the comments at this question.

Each example in a batch is processed by all the heads. Therefore, order doesn't matter. Suppose the batch size is 1, then it is like (example-1,head-1), (example-1,head-2)... (example-1,head-n) for the first iteration. It will change to example-2 in the next iteration and so on. If the batch size is two, it can also be processed in parallel (independently), in that case, it would be (example-1,head-1),(example-2,head-1)
